# How to view debug information or error information when using Laravel (7) filesystem calls?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using the Laravel filesystem calls - for example: Storage::disk('sftp')->put and it is working fine but I am wondering how I can view debug or error information if there ever were the need?

So for example if the file upload failed, how would I see that?   When I first wrote the code it was not working and there was no Laravel exception screen and nothing in the laravel.log.

Comment: Can you share more details? "Not working" is a bit broad - what did you do to resolve the issue? If there is no exception thrown, it would be pretty hard to react

Comment: My code is currently working.   I am asking if there is a way to see output from the filesystem calls in Laravel.     So for example if I were to use an sftp client such as filezilla I would see messages scroll by as it connects and transfers information.   I want to see that from Laravel.

Answer (score 4):

I noted this in FileSystemAdapter:

```php
} catch (UnableToWriteFile|UnableToSetVisibility $e) {
    throw_if($this->throwsExceptions(), $e);

    return false;
}
```

And `throwsExceptions()` checks for `$this->config['throw']`, so in `config/filesystems.php` I added to the config array of my s3 bucket `'throw' => true,` and now the errors are thrown rather than just returning false.

```php
    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => 'us-east-1',
        'bucket' => 'abcd',
        'throw' => true, // Failures will throw exceptions
    ],
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm in the same case.

I'm using Laravel Storage library with `league/flysystem-sftp` for sftp transfer. Here is the *problematic* line.

```
Storage::disk(self::REMOTE_DISK)->putFileAs($destFolder, $this->localFilePath, $destFilename);
```

Most of the time all is working fine. File is copied from local to remote without any problem.

But sometimes one problem occurs and I failed to understand what's occured during the transfer.
All I can do (at this time) is

```
$result = Storage::disk(self::REMOTE_DISK)->putFileAs($destFolder, $this->localFilePath, $destFilename);
if ($result === false) {
    $exception = new FileUploadFailureException("file upload has failed");
}
```

Is there a better way to debug one sftp connection trouble ?